# WCF - IIS deployment not working

Tags: wcf

I have deployed the WCF wervice on the IIS by creating a VirtualDirectory.

While accessing from firefox it is generating the following message:

```
XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Location: http://localhost/Calculator/Service.svc
Line Number 9, Column 2:<%@ Service Class="Calculator.CalculatorService" %>
-^
```

What is wrong?

Comment: 158 questions and you've accepted just over half of them. Was there something wrong with the other answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the WCF extensions aren't registered with IIS correctly and IIS is serving the raw .svc file instead of executing your service.

Make sure your Virtual Directory has ASP.NET v2.0 enabled, and then use [ServiceModelReg.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732012.aspx) to register the WCF extensions on it.